# Server 2008 Web Edition limitations

Tags: windows-server-2008

Can anyone point me at very specific details of what the limitations of the Web Edition of Windows Server 2008 are? I have seen the higher level comparisson charts of the various editions but no detailed specifics.

I understand they removed the inability to install SQL Server and significantly raised the RAM and CPU limits. But a little googling indicates that in Server 2003 the Web Edition has a limit of 10 inbound UNC connections to keep people from using it as a file server. Does this limit still exist in Server 2008? Are there other limits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/editions-overview.aspx

> Windows Web Server 2008 is designed to be used **specifically as a single-purpose Web server**, and delivers on a rock-solid foundation of Web infrastructure capabilities in the next-generation Windows Server 2008. Integrated with the newly re-architected IIS 7.0, ASP.NET, and the Microsoft .NET Framework, Windows Web Server 2008 enables any organization to rapidly deploy Web pages, Web sites, Web applications, and Web services.

There are some really good pages under the "editions" link at the top of that page as well. Specifically http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/compare-roles.aspx states that the Web edition does NOT support File Services.

Comment: Yep, I saw these comparrisons and the fact that it does not support the File Services Role. But does that mean that it in fact cannot even create a Share or is it more subtle (like the 10 inbound UNC connections limit of 2003)?

Comment: AFAIK it means you cannot even create a Share, because you cannot install the File Server role. I guess one way to see would be to get the eval version (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=B1CB6D54-7268-4791-9C5D-CDB21516BF5A&displaylang=en) and see.

Comment: So it turns out you can in fact create shares. I have been unable to find any limitations with them either. However you cannot access the "Share and Storage Management" mmc snap-in. It appears the StorageMgmt snap-in is missing even though the menu item exists within the Administrative Tools menu. All share mgmt must be done through right clicking a shared folder and choosing Properties then using the Share and Permissions tabs.

Comment: Your link in the post is broken

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the comparison pages on the Microsoft website, be sure to check the [Licensing page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/licensing-web-server.aspx).

> Windows Web Server 2008 can be used
>   solely to deploy Internet-accessible
>   Web pages, Web sites, Web
>   applications, Web services, and POP3
>   mail serving

Comment: Thanks, I did not consider the legal aspect.

Answer (score 5):

Following on from the answers above (the pdf isn't that easy to see on the pages).

Here is a direct link to a PDF overview on Microsoft's site of each server role (feature set) available in each edition.

[Comparison of Server 2008 R2 Editions](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/C/6/FC6006B5-866E-42C1-88F8-9AC4B8BC610D/WS%20Brand%20Pages%20-%20Editions%20Comparison%20Guide.pdf)

[image: Screen shot of the Windows Server 2008 R2 Edition Comparison by Server Role]

Answer (score 4):

We are running a Server 2008 Web Edition with SQL server 2008 on it.

Comment: As noted by the OP: "I understand they removed the inability to install SQL Server and significantly raised the RAM and CPU limits."

Comment: Apparently, you *can* install SQL Server on Windows Web Server.

http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/04/15/windows-web-server-2008-and-sql-server-2005.aspx

Comment: @Josh Yeager, Yep, thats why i mentioned it.

Comment: How well does SQL Server run on it? What edition of SQL Server is there?

Answer (score 3):

See here for comparison

[Edition Comparison by Server Role](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-roles.aspx)

Also see here:
[Server 2008 Web Edition limitations](https://serverfault.com/questions/40564/server-2008-web-edition-limitations)

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the Web Edition to be a Domain Controller, Terminal Server, Hyper-V host, etc.  It is a Web Server only.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft the main difference is that the "web edition" includes Microsoft's own web server (IIS). More differences can be seen on the following page:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-editions-overview.aspx

Comment: All versions of Windows include IIS.