# What's the difference between Windows Server 2008 Standard and Web?

Tags: windows-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Server 2008 Web Edition limitations](https://serverfault.com/questions/40564/server-2008-web-edition-limitations)

What's the difference between Windows Server 2008 Standard and Windows Server 2008 Web?